# Cordova/Phonegap File plugin searching file, confused about documentation

Tags: android, cordova

I'm confused about the file plugin for cordova, this is my code :

```
function checkIfFileExists(path){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 10*1024*1024, function(fileSystem){
            fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
        }, getFSFail);
}


checkIfFileExists("Framaroot-1.6.1.apk");
}
```

First problem : If i replace "root" by "sdcard" (like the doc https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md ), it's not working. When i read the doc, i understand that we can do that. I'm wrong ?

Second problem : when i put "root", it's works, but root is not the sdcard, so why the function return me a true for search the Framaroot apk (he is in the root of sdcard) ?

Third : If i want to search a particular file in destination that is know, what is the syntax for search the file test.txt in /sdcard/Android/data/com/domain.myapp/ directory ? I use "cdvfile" ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but I'm researching the same areas right now.

I think your first issue is a permissions one. The file plugin docs (which are atrocious, by the way) point to this [Android dev page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), which mentions needing  `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions for read and write access, respectively. You have to do this manually in your `platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml` file if you're using the CLI, but if you're on PhoneGap Build, there's a tweak to the top-level config.xml file that you can make that will copy the block over for you:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" overwrite="true">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</gap:config-file>
```

Be sure to add the `<xmlnls>` for android at the top of the config.xml file so that it'll parse correctly on PG Build:

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlnls:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>
```